# Greater than Cross field validation in Angular Validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my form some fields are depended on other fields. So I want to validate the control when the value changes will occur. I know about the global validator on formgroup. but I don't want to use that due to some other issues.

Scenario : If user enters a value in Car Amount field based on that user cannot enters  the greater than value in Premium Amount textbox.

I have applied a custom validator on 'premiumAmount' field, but when I change the value in the 'carAmount' field then premiumAmount validation will not fire.

How to resolve this?

Comment: i believe all you need is proper data-binding. I would say, go through https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: You should either add a validator on a form group containing both fields (and thus fix your mysterious other issues), or listen to the changes of the carAmount value to explicitly re-validate the premiumAmount. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges, https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making Custom Greater than validation, this can be achieved through greaterThan validator of @rxweb/reactive-form-validators.

You just need to mention in your greatherThan validator in your formGroup. Here is the code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            carAmount:['',], 
            premiumAmount:['', RxwebValidators.greaterThan({fieldName:'carAmount' })], 
        });
    }
```

Here is the [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r64rmj?file=src/app/greater-than-field-name.component.ts).

Comment: I did exactly the same like it is presnted in example, but in my validation error is not visible when editing carAmount, only editing premiumAmount showing me an error. Example scenario:

put 300 to premiumAmount
put 100 to carAmount

In my case error will not appear for that scenario